# Dashboard Panels/Boxes designs

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create boxes designs in a simple HTML/JS/CSS format, like the one's made in this [link](http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/)

The top panel of numbers shown in the link is what I need to create and it must be dynamic.

Currently, I just have a basic table in HTML with 2 cells, and the number keeps changing depending on date-pickers and dropdowns. My data is connected in the form of CSV (using d3.csv)

what is the approach to follow to build some panel with dynamic numbers? Should I use twitter bootstrap, dashing etc? 
I can't use frameworks/servers, want to do it in basic HTML/JS/CSS format.

Any help is highly appreciated

UPDATE :

HTML Code :

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <h1>
                    <img src="images/header.png" alt= " This is header! "height = "100px"; width ="1350px">
                </h1>

                <p>From date : </p>
                <input id="StartDate" type="text" value="09/11/2015" name="StartDate">
                <p>To Date : </p>
                <input id="EndDate" class="datepicker" type="text" value="15/11/2015" name="EndDate">



                <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <i class="fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                <div class="box-text">Customers Targeted</div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="huge" id="cc">26</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="panel panel-green">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                <div class="huge" id="rr">12</div>
                                                <div>Recharge Revenue Increment ($)</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                <div class="huge">124</div>
                                                <div>New Orders!</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="panel panel-red">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <i class="fa fa-support fa-5x"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                <div class="huge">13</div>
                                                <div>Support Tickets!</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.row -->


                    </div>

                </div>
```

I have made a panel (boxes)  something like [this](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/)
(Look at top panel of boxes with numbers changing)

Now, I have understood the process, and want to design something with my own CSS (earlier was twitter bootstrap and multiple css) , how should I go about doing the same?

Comment: The question is unrecevable since you did not provide any code to start with, which means you ask us to do a specific work from scratch, and this is not the aim of SO.

Comment: Where is your code ?